# what causes this error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, zip

I keep getting this error on app build:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ziparchive W 08-29 15:58:11  1796 22504] Zip: didn't find signature at start of lfh, offset=5439573
> error: failed to open APK: Invalid offset.

I already tried to clean and rebuild the project, deleting Gradle cache and downgrading google dependencies as suggested in another question but the error persists.